# How to prevent the header text from moving down when navbar breadcrumb is clicked on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

The problem is that in the mobile device when I click on the breadcrumb then the header text and button moves down outside taking it outside the header image.
Is it possible to keep the button and the text static without having to move the nav outside of the header.
It doesn't happen if nav is outside the header.
https://jsfiddle.net/f4cejopu/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style type="text/css">
      
.row {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.navbar-custom {
  background: transparent; !important;
    z-index: 9999;
}
header {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/w8jxzG4.jpg");
  height: 80vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.navbar-custom {
  background: transparent !important;
  
}

header h1{
  color: #fff;
}

.header-content{
  padding-top: 14rem;
    padding-bottom: 10rem;
}
    </style>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Space</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Explore</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Shop
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"> <!-- margin-right auto -->
      <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
       <li>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="header-content">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto">
  <h1>Welcome To The Space</h1>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto">
  <button class="btn">Register for a trip</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix to prevent the `nav` text from pushing down the `content` is to remove it from the DOM flow with positioning.

```
.navbar.navbar-custom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

You'll notice your content will shift up (as the `navbar` no longer affects elements around it - similar to removing it from `<header>`). The easy fix here is just to apply an offset to the content. Something like:

```
.header-content {
    margin-top: 3.4375rem // or ~55px
}
```

Or, leverage the existing `padding-top`, like:

```
.header-content {
    padding-top: calc(3.4375rem + 4rem);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wmtsgxe4/

Before:
[image]

After (text is behind the gray navbar):
[image]